# Какие есть построчные онлайн компиляторы?

Tags: python, компиляция

т.е. чтобы туда загрузить код, а он его прогонял прям по одной строке и где то отображал что на данный момент прохождения в ней находится

на этом сайте видел, как некоторые из участников прикрепляли код сразу в каком-то окне, и там была снизу окна ссылка на сайт, вот там компилятор получается, но не помню как называется

Comment: `прикрепляли код сразу в каком-то окне` вот такое окно:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1227429 ?

Comment: @Danis да.......

Comment: это работает только с `html/css/js`

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/104086/ https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger

Comment: @Danis блин, ну где то с этого сайта запускал

Comment: @КириллМалышев немного не тот что искал

Comment: @Андр Например почти онлайн интерпретатором является обычный Jupyter ноутбук, сервера для онлайн запуска его всюду есть, например вот бесплатный от гугла [https://colab.research.google.com/](https://colab.research.google.com/), это не совсем интерактивная консоль но по впечатлению от использования очень близка, тоже исполнение и запуск можно по 1 ячейке, за раз можно одну или несколько строк кода писать и выполнять.